# How to adjust TSQL code to truncate only tables of the dim schema?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following to modify..

```
DECLARE @tablename AS VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR (1000)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tables') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tables

SELECT *
INTO   #tables
FROM   sys.tables

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM   #tables)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @tablename = name
        FROM   #tables
        SELECT @sql = 'truncate table ' + @tablename;
        PRINT @sql
        EXECUTE (@sql)
        DELETE #tables
        WHERE  name = @tablename;
    END
```

The above code will truncate all tables in a database, which is what I need however I only want this to work on tables that are part of the "dim" schema.

As an example, I have the following tables..

dbo.sales
dim.employee
dim.office

I'd like the script to only truncate the "dim" schema tables and not the dbo.sales table.

This is assuming that I don't have any PK/FK (as I have another code handling the drop/create of PK/FK).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, `FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_name([schema_id]) = N'dim';` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']' + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND s.name = 'dim'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dim].[test1]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dim].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dim].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dim].[test4]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name as name 
INTO   #tables
FROM   sys.tables
where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dim'
```

Comment: I added your suggestion but now it shows.. Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object "ITEM_PACK_SIZE" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: Is that the name of a table in your 'dim' schema?

Comment: yes, the table name is dim.ITEM_PACK_SIZE I think the issue is it somehow is not parsing the "dim." in the final truncate table TSQL.

Comment: Edited my answer. This will give you the schema-qualified table name and, hopefully, will fix the issue for you.

Comment: The SELECT statement is followed by another select. Typo?

Comment: Oops - fixed typo. Thanks for catching it, Louie Bao!